# Is there a collaborative git repo for mathematical proofs?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

Is there a collaborative git repo for mathematical proofs?

I have seen some sites that resemble this but they have been in wiki form or bound to a specific proof engine, and the ones I have seen only covers basics.

Comment: [There's ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: Yes, proof wiki is really good. Planetmath seems offline when I try to visit it. Encyclopedia of math is good too. These are the ones I know about. Would be nice with a repo though.